# Problema en XAMP, al iniciar MYSQL muestra este error

Tags: mysql

Tengo un error cuando inicio el servicio de xamp, en mysql, inicia, y se autoapaga, y me manda el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Funcionaba normal, y deje de utilizarlo una semana, en ese lapso use JDowloader con cambio de proxy y use una VPN para algunas descargas, tal vez sirva de algo.

este es el log:

```
2019-10-19 20:27:04 1cdc InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2019-10-19 20:27:04 7388 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2019-10-19 20:27:05 7388 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2019-10-19 20:27:05 7388 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2019-10-19 20:27:05 7388 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-10-19 20:27:05 7388 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2019-10-19 20:27:05 7388 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-10-19 20:27:05 7388 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2019-10-19 20:27:05 7388 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2019-10-19 20:27:05 7388 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-10-19 20:27:05 7388 [Note] InnoDB: The first specified data file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1 did not exist: a new database to be created!
2019-10-19 20:27:05 7388 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1 size to 10 MB
2019-10-19 20:27:05 7388 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 size to 5 MB
2019-10-19 20:27:05 7388 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile1 size to 5 MB
2019-10-19 20:27:05 7388 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 to C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile0
2019-10-19 20:27:05 7388 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45781
2019-10-19 20:27:05 7388 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
2019-10-19 20:27:05 7388 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
2019-10-19 20:27:05 7388 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-10-19 20:27:05 7388 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2019-10-19 20:27:05 7388 [Note] InnoDB: Foreign key constraint system tables created
2019-10-19 20:27:05 7388 [Note] InnoDB: Creating tablespace and datafile system tables.
2019-10-19 20:27:05 7388 [Note] InnoDB: Tablespace and datafile system tables created.
2019-10-19 20:27:05 7388 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-10-19 20:27:05 7388 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.41-84.1 started; log sequence number 0
Cannot find checkpoint record at LSN (1,0x208b)

2019-10-19 20:27:06 7388 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files
2019-10-19 20:27:06 1652 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2019-10-19 20:27:06 7388 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2019-10-19 20:27:06 7388 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2019-10-19 20:27:06 7388 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-10-19 20:27:06 7388 [ERROR] Aria engine is not enabled or did not start. The Aria engine must be enabled to continue as mysqld was configured with --with-aria-tmp-tables
2019-10-19 20:27:06 7388 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Answer (score -1):

Lo solucioné reinstalandolo todo de nuevo, y borre todas mis bases de datos, como solo eran de práctica, no tuve problema